# Solr increasing maxBooleanClauses not working

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

While filtering a field for multiple values joined by `OR` clause like:

```
http:://localhost:8983/solr/dev_keyspace.sample_core/select?q=*%3A*&fq=field1%3A("ONE"+OR+"TWO"...)&wt=json&indent=true
```

following error was thrown:

`Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/dev_keyspace.sample_core: maxClauseCount is set to 1024`

Followed the instructions [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/search/searchIndexConfig.html) to bump the `maxBooleanClause` value. Tried reloading and drop/create the core. The error is still persistent.

Environment:

1. DSEv6.0.7
2. Apache Solr™ 6.0.1.1.2407 (Provided by DSE)

Comment: After changing the config you need to reload the solr core

Comment: Missed to menton, reloading or drop/create not working. Updated the question.

Comment: DSE service restart after reindex worked!

Answer (score 1):

As for Sol 9 you also need to set the `maxBooleanClause` globally, for this you can do one of these options:

**OPTION 1:** Change the `solr.xml` file replacing `<int name="maxBooleanClauses">${solr.max.booleanClauses:1024}</int>` to `<int name="maxBooleanClauses">50000</int>`

**OPTION 2:** Add `SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.max.booleanClauses=50000` to the `/etc/default/solr.in.sh` file

> Obviously `50000` is here just an example, you should add this value to your collections `solrconfig.xml` files but be careful with huge values because they can easily choke Solr with too many boolean clauses.